# Checking if jQuery has been loaded in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I am using the following piece of code to make sure that jQuery has been loaded in page before I execute the main body of javascript in my bookmarklet. Is there any chance this code fails to load jQuery properly in any browser?

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
    script.onload = function () {
        foo();
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
} else {
    foo();
}

function foo() {
    // bookmarklet code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any chance this code fails to load jQuery properly in any browser?

Not unless the page in question was loaded from a local resource rather than via `http` / `https`. In that case, the protocol-relative URL will fail.

You'll want to reverse the order in which you set the `src` and `onload` properties, though; if the resource is in cache, the event can be fired before you hook up the handler (JavaScript in browsers is single-threaded other than Web Workers, but *browsers* are not single-threaded).

Also, there's no need to wrap an additional function around `foo`:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = foo;
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
} else {
    foo();
}

function foo() {
    // bookmarklet code goes here
}
```

---

If you want to handle the protocol issue so it works with `file:` URLs and such, that's easy enough to do:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var protocol = location.protocol;
    if (protocol !== "http:" && protocol !== "https:") {
        protocol = "http:";
    }
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = foo;
    script.src = protocol + "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
} else {
    foo();
}

function foo() {
    // bookmarklet code goes here
}
```

Comment: I really appreicate your advice :)

Comment: @Meysam: No worries. :-)